# How to select comments with child comments from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

'comments'

```
| id | content | user_id | article_id | parent_id |
```

'users'

```
| id | name | photo |
```

And my queries are:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT comments.id, comments.content, users.name, 
users.photo FROM comments, users WHERE comments.article_id = '".$get_id."' 
AND comments.parent_id = 0 AND comments.user_id = users.id");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $id = $res['id'];
  $content = $res['content'];
  $name = $res['name'];
  $photo = $res['photo'];

  echo $photo;
  echo $name;
  echo $content;

  $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT comments.id, comments.content, users.name, 
  users.photo FROM comments, users WHERE comments.article_id = '".$get_id."' 
AND comments.parent_id = '".$id."' AND comments.user_id = users.id");
  while($res2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
  {
    $id2 = $res2['id'];
    $content2 = $res2['content'];
    $name2 = $res2['name'];
    $photo2 = $res2['photo'];

    echo $photo2;
    echo $name2;
    echo $content2;
  }
}
?>
```

It doesn't work properly. It shows 1 parent and 1 child comment in each nest although there are several child comments.

How can I fix and minimize it? Can it be done by using only one query?

Thank you!

Comment: Please stop using PHP's archaic, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: What to use then? Can you share some links?

Comment: Use MySQLi or better PDO https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score -1):

`JOIN` the table on itself.

Change your query to:

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.content, users.name, 
users.photo FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id JOIN 
comments c ON comments.id = 
c.parent_id  WHERE 
comments.article_id = '".$get_id."' 
AND comments.parent_id = '".$id."'
```

You don't need the second query, here's the full code:

```php
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT comments.id, comments.content, users.name, 
users.photo FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id JOIN 
comments c ON comments.id = 
c.parent_id  WHERE 
comments.article_id = '".$get_id."'");

while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $id = $res['id'];
  $content = $res['content'];
  $name = $res['name'];
  $photo = $res['photo'];

  echo $photo;
  echo $name;
  echo $content;
 } 

?>
```

Comment: What about comma in this part: `FROM comments , users` Is that a right syntax or just a misspelling?

Comment: Updated my answer, please see

Comment: Just use `SELECT DISTINCT ..` to remove duplicates

Comment: `"SELECT DISTINCT comments.id, comments.content, users.name, 
users.photo FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id JOIN 
comments c ON comments.id = 
c.parent_id  WHERE 
comments.article_id = '".$get_id."'"`

Comment: I added LEFT JOIN `SELECT DISTINCT comments.id, comments.content, users.name, users.photo FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id LEFT JOIN comments c ON comments.id = c.parent_id WHERE comments.article_id = '".$get_id."'` Now the output order is: `[id=1, parent_id=0], [id=2, parent_id=1], [id=4, parent_id=1], [id=3, parent_id=0], [id=5, parent_id=2], [id=6, parent_id=1]` It's a little bit strange

Comment: Hi, what should be the desired output order then?

Comment: you can figure the order you want by playing with the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score -1):

Just use a [JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) to fetch the comments and with all the children.

```
SELECT users.id userID, users.name, users.photo , childrenComments.*,   
   parentComments.id cpId, parentComments.content cpContent,
   parentComments.user_id cpUser_id,parentComments.article_id cpArticleId
FROM users JOIN (SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE id=0) parentComments 
ON users.id=parentComments.user_id LEFT JOIN Comment childrenComments
ON parentComments.id=childrenComments.parent_id;
```

Then you can the loop through the result to print it appropriately. This would be better as you would have to run just a single query.